# Authentication error in mongodb 3.0 using spring data 1.8.0

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

**DbConnection code:**

```
  package com.sam.rest.config;

    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
    public class SpringMongoDBConfiguration {

    @Value("${internal.mongodb.database}")
    String databaseName;
    @Value("${internal.mongodb.username}")
    String userName;
    @Value("${internal.mongodb.password}")
    String password;
    @Value("${internal.mongodb.host}")
    String host;




    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev()   {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
    public @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {

        MongoClientURI uri=new MongoClientURI("mongodb://"+userName+":"+password+"@"+host+"/"+databaseName);
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(uri), databaseName);
    }

    public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());

        return mongoTemplate;

    }

}
```

**Exception is:**

```
com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [authenticate]: { "serverUsed" : "" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
    com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:88)
    com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134)
    com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:311)
    com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:285)
    com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
    com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
    com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
    com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:412)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$14.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:1600)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$14.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:1598)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:446)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getCollectionNames(MongoTemplate.java:1598)
    com.eda.rest.model.dao.MessageDao.isConnected(MessageDao.java:129)
    com.eda.rest.service.MessageService.isConnected(MessageService.java:111)
    com.eda.rest.controller.MessageController.home(MessageController.java:45)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.eda.rest.config.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:64)
```

Comment: how to resolve this error.its working in console program but not working in spring mvc.Please any one can help me.........